# displaying Video Image in winRT gridview

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, mediaelement

I'm developing a Windows 8 Store App, I have this problem, 
I want the user to add the videos from a file picker and i managed it,
the problem is I want to display the videos images in a GridView, 
like snap shot of the video in a certain position, i tried the media element and it's not working
also an image and it doesn't make sense.

Comment: You would probably need to use Media Foundation and Perhaps DirectX and WIC to save it in a sort of thumbnail cache.

Answer (score 0):

There might not be a pure C# solution to this problem. Perhaps SharpDX would let you do that, but I haven't tried and I don't know if it was done before. If you look at these two threads:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/fil-PH/wingameswithdirectx/thread/05731d4f-5b7f-4ed1-8e28-94604655139e

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wingameswithdirectx/thread/ffacd05c-6e9e-43bf-b691-99127240730c

-- you should see that there is a [`TransferVideoFrame`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448021%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method you can use to copy a frame from a video stream to a DirectX texture. The [Media engine native C++ video playback sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-Engine-Playback-ce1c82f0/) shows how you can use it natively. If you search for TransferVideoFrame+SharpDX - you can find [this sample](http://code.google.com/p/sharpdx/source/browse/#git/Samples/Win8/MiniCubeVideoTexture) that uses the [SharpDX version of this method](http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/t-sharpdx-mediafoundation-mediaengine) in C#. After you transfer that frame to a texture - you can either copy the contents of the texture to a `WriteableBitmap` using the `Map` and `Unmap` methods like [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205131%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can also save it to a file either using `BitmapEncoder` a [here](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/f7a69dc2a5d9#WinRTXamlToolkit/Imaging/WriteableBitmapSaveExtensions.cs) or directly from the DirectX texture to a file using WIC or say SharpDX Toolkit as in [here](http://code.google.com/p/sharpdx/source/search?q=texture%20save&origq=texture%20save&btnG=Search%20Trunk). You will probably want to build a cache of thumbnails to avoid having to process the videos every time you display the list, so saving to a file is something you should do anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your own solution that you quoted elsewhere that should work for at least some videos:

```
var thumb = await
    storageFile.GetThumbnailAsync(
        Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailMode.PicturesView,
        1000,
        Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailOptions.UseCurrentScale);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `GetThumbnailAsync()`, which works just as well. You don't even need to get the video properties or anything like that. If the StorageFile is loaded, this should work for a normal video of any format.